# How to test a remote actions which uploads binary data?

Tags: apex, unit-test, managed-package

I have a method that looks something like the following:

```
public static String uploadFile(String filename, String fileData, String parentId){
        String UserId = UserInfo.getUserId();

        String user = UserInfo.getUserID();
        if(fileData==null)
            return String.valueOf('Invalid file data.');

        String base64 = fileData.substring(fileData.indexOf(',')+1);
        Blob actualdata = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64);

        if(actualdata.size()<=0)
            return String.valueOf('File size cannot be greater then 10MB.');

        Attachment att = new Attachment(ParentId=parentId, Body=actualdata);
        att.Name = filename;
        insert(att);
        return parentId + ',' + att.Id + ',' + att.Name;
    }
```

How would I write a unit test for this? Should I hard code a base64 encoded binary file? Is there a better/easier way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create `Blob` type file in test class and simulate upload as by adding similar statements in `testmethod`:

```
String fileData = 'I am String to be converted in base64 encoding!';
String fileDateBase64 = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Bolb.valueOf(fileData));
String mimetype = 'text/csv;base64,';
String fileName = 'SampleTest.csv';

String finalFileData = mimetype+fileDateBase64;

...
// Generate parent record here so ParentId can be sent in method
...

// Real test begin
String result = UnknownClassName.uploadFile(fileName, finalFileData, parentId);

// add proper assert.
System.assert(3,result.split(',').size());
System.assert(fileName,result.split(',')[2]);
```

Not sure this can be covered as you would get exception for encoding nothing:

```
   if(actualdata.size()<=0)
        return String.valueOf('File size cannot be greater then 10MB.');
```

Comment: Yeah that last bit is nonsensical. It is also totally unnecessary to do `String.valueOf`...considering the input is already a `String` instance.